# multiply 2 matrices from form inputs. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I got an assignment to multiply 2 matrices that the user inputs in the form text box like so:
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
So I created a var matrix1 and matrix2 that take the string values with a command document.getElementById("matrixID").value, but I don't know how to separate them in their own values, creating an array or a matrix of a variable (setting 1,2,3... as separate matrix/array values).
I'm not allowed to use JQuery (even though I don't think it's needed anyway). The current code looks like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Matrix multiply</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function calc(){
                var matrix1string = document.getElementById("m1").value;
                var matrix2string = document.getElementById("m2").value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            Matrix 1: <input type="text" id="m1" name="mat1" style="width: 500px"><br>
            Matrix 2: <input type="text" id="m2" name="mat2" style="width: 500px"><br>
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calc();"><br><br>
            -Result: <input type="text" id="rez" name="mat2" style="width: 500px" readonly>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var matrix1 = JSON.parse(matrix1string);
var matrix2 = JSON.parse(matrix2string);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! How do I use elements of those matrices from there on? with matrix1[0], matrix1[1] etc. or is it a true matrix from that point (matrix[0][0] etc.)

Comment: From this point on it's a two-dimensional array, so you can access the elements like so: matrix1[0][1] or matrix2[2][1]

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! :) edit: It'll be accepted in ~6 mins.

Comment: The ~6 mins. are over... ;)

Comment: Sorry, got caught up! Ty again for help, it solved the problem :)